# PHP: How to remove comma in a for loop?

Tags: php

```
  <?php 
    for ($i = 10; $i < 101; $i = $i + 10) {
    echo $i;        
    }   
  ?>
```

I'm starting to learn PHP and this is the code I'm working on. What I'm trying to do is remove the comma on the last item that will display (e.g. 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,) I've searched the forum and all I see are methods for "foreach"...Any suggestions, replies are appreciated.

Comment: i don't see anything in this code that would output a comma

Comment: `echo implode(',', range(10, 100, 10));`

Answer (score 1):

There is no comma in your code or it's output but your question is still understandable and you just missed posting the code line which outputs those commas. You simply have to check if this is the last iteration of the loop and if so don't print comma

```
echo $i;
if($i<100)    //currently you don't have this check so you get an extra comma
 echo ",";
```

Output

```
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = array();

for ($i = 10; $i < 101; $i += 10) {
    $result[] = $i;
}

echo implode(", ", $result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this,

```
$result = array();
for ( $i = 10; $i < 101; $i = $i + 10 ){
    $result[] = $i;
}
echo implode(", ", $result);
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array, write `implode(',', $array)`. If it's not, save output from each iteration to a variable(say `$output`), then, write `substr($output,0,-1)`.

```
$output = "";
for ($i = 10; $i < 101; $i = $i + 10) {
 $output .= $i.",";        
}   
echo substr($output,0,-1);
```

Your code doesn't relate to your question/description, though!

Comment: I forgot the rest of the code for the display...Apologies...thanks for your feedback...I'll try it as well.